# Как конвертировать float число в строку?

Tags: php, float, конвертация, sprintf

Как универсально и безопасно сконвертировать любое число в строку, и без лишних нулей в конце?

Пробовал через `sprintf`, выводит не то что нужно, а для `number_format` нужны параметры которые неизвестны

```
$num = 1e-8;

$str = (string) sprintf('%f', $num) // "0.000000", должно "0.00000001"
```

Comment: Могу подсказать как это сделать только с заданной точностью, не с бесконечной :)

Comment: @Владимир в этом проблема, точность всегда разная, нужно как то универсально. Вообще странно, весь гугл обгуглил ни чего рабочего не нашел, неужели это невыполнимая штука))

Comment: Не до конца понятна какую задачу вы решаете. Если задача в том чтобы корректно выводить число, то возможно спецификатор %e вам поможет. Он будет выведет число в нотации 1e-8

Если же задача чтобы вывести чисто в формате 0.00000001 то вероятней всего вам надо будет писать свою функцию.

Comment: @newman это для записи в базу в виде строки для последующего простого вывода на экран в читаемом виде для пользователей

Comment: как то универсально но с ограниченой точностью, например максимум сотня знаков после запятой, устроит?